# creating time and memory efficient php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have to rewrite my code so that it will be iffecient when it comes to memory and execution time..

what the script does is creat a mysql dump wherein the data are get into huge data table and insert into another database.

The data that being process here is about 17 MB of table data and eating about 62 MB of Memory. any suggestion how to lower down the memory usage coz in future it will go bigger and bigger?

```
<?php
ini_set("max_execution_time", "28800");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include(dirname(__FILE__)."/includes/prepend.php");

$table = "source_table";
$target = "destination_table";

echo 'Initial: ' . number_format((memory_get_usage()/ 1024) / 1024 , 0, '.', ',') . " MB <br>";

$db = new DB_cms();
$db->beginTransaction();

$return.= 'DELETE FROM '.$target.'; '. "\n\n";

if($db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table)){
    $i=0;
    $itemList = array();

    while($db->next_record()){

        $itemList[$i]["guid"] = $db->f("guid");
        $itemList[$i]["title"] = $db->f("title");
        $itemList[$i]["description"] = $db->f("description");
        $itemList[$i]["copyright"] = $db->f("copyright");
        $itemList[$i]["mediaType"] = $db->f("wapMediaType");
        $itemList[$i]["price"] = $db->f("displayPrice");
        $itemList[$i]["category"] = $db->f("category");
        $itemList[$i]["thumbnail"] = $db->f("thumbnail");

        //begin json  data
        $json = new Services_JSON();
        $keywords_arr = $json->decode($db->f("keywords"));

        foreach($keywords_arr as $key => $value){
             $itemList[$i][$key] = $value;
        }

        $credit_arr = $json->decode($db->f("credit"));
        foreach($credit_arr as $c => $credit){
            $itemList[$i][str_replace(' ','',$c)] = $credit;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $toInsert = array();

    foreach($itemList as $items => $item){
        $guid = mysql_real_escape_string($item["guid"]);
        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($item["title"]);
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string(ereg_replace('"', "",$item["description"]));
        $copyright = mysql_real_escape_string($item["copyright"]);
        $mediaType = mysql_real_escape_string($item["mediaType"]);
        $price = mysql_real_escape_string($item["price"]);
        $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(ereg_replace('"', "",$item["keywords"]));
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string(ereg_replace('"', "",$item["category"]));
        $thumbnail = mysql_real_escape_string($item["thumbnail"]);
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        //json decoded  data
        $artist = mysql_real_escape_string($item["artist"]);
        $label = mysql_real_escape_string($item["label"]);
        $genre = mysql_real_escape_string($item["genre"]);
        $media_format = mysql_real_escape_string($item["mediaformat"]);
        $country = mysql_real_escape_string($item["country"]);
        $album_title = mysql_real_escape_string(ereg_replace('"', "",$item["albumtitle"]));

        $toInsert[] = "('0', $guid, 'NULL', '".$mediaType."', '".$category."', '".$keywords."', '".$title."', '".$artist."', '".$album_title."', '".$genre."', '".$label."', '".$media_format."', '".$country."', '".$description."', '".$thumbnail."', '".$price."', '".$copyright."', '".$date."', '0', '".$date."', '0', 'active')";
    }

    $sqlStart = "INSERT INTO `".$target ."` (`SortVar`, `Guid`, `Space`, `MediaType`, `Category`, `Keywords`, `Title`, `Artist`, `Album`, `Genre`, `Label`, `Mediaformat`, `Country`, `Description`, `Thumbnail`, `Price`, `Copyright`, `DateCreated`, `CreatedBy`, `DateModified`, `ModifiedBy`, `Status`) VALUES";

    foreach (array_chunk($toInsert, 100) as $insertSet) {
        $return.= $sqlStart . implode(', ', $insertSet);
        $return.="; \n";
    }

    //save file
    $handle = fopen(ABSOLUTE_DUMP_PATH.'file'.'.sql','w+');
    if(fwrite($handle,$return)){
        fclose($handle);
        $ret = true;
    } else {
        $ret = false;
    }

    $usage = memory_get_usage();
    $total_usage = ($usage / 1024) / 1024;
    echo 'Peak: ' . number_format($total_usage, 0, '.', ',') . " MB<br>";
    echo 'End: ' . number_format($total_usage, 0, '.', ',') . " MB<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this between two tables in 1 database (which is what your current code appears to do), do it all in one SQL statement.  Don't ever bring the data down to PHP if you don't have to.  You'll want to use MySQL's [insert...select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).  The query should look not totally unlike this:

```
INSERT INTO `target_table` (`SortVar`, `Guid`, `Space`, `MediaType`, `Category`, `Keywords`, `Title`, `Artist`, `Album`, `Genre`, `Label`, `Mediaformat`, `Country`, `Description`, `Thumbnail`, `Price`, `Copyright`, `DateCreated`, `CreatedBy`, `DateModified`, `ModifiedBy`, `Status`)
  SELECT *
  FROM `source_table`;
```

Comment: If you look at the source, there's the keywords bit in the first part (selecting the date). It doesn't look as if there's a 1-to-1 correlation between the two tables - hence, a direct sql copy is not just insert into select from. That being said, you might still be able to work something out by using string splits in sql - but I wouldn't rely on it, looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading everything into an array, and then write it out to the destination file, try restructuring your program in such a way that you write things out incrementally.